# when i resize the window, some gap is coming besides of expanded div

Tags: css, css-float

when i am resize the window which div is expanded that besides gap is coming. Can anybody solve this please? http://jsfiddle.net/yVwnZ/
Thanks.

Comment: its working very fine what is the real problem? expanded div have content that why its bigger then the others, and when you resize they all share the same gap which is correct, what exactly you want?

Comment: when i have 50 or 100 boxes that content 3 is looks odd with the beside spaces.

Comment: that beside space is created by margin:5px; in your code and you need to fix the height of the div if you want to look them similar.

Comment: The real things is I really didnt get your situation what you want what is the issue so cant say...

Comment: actually this is for online messenger. every buddy blocks will come side by side. when i click on the div, it will expand and shows the details.

Comment: as per your requirement its working fine coz its not mandatory to have same amount of details in each user's block, so i guess it's working fine your div will expand according to the content

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive what you mean, but I think you're misunderstanding how the float: left is working. When the window is very narrow, there isn't room for the divs to float, so they stack up vertically. As the container gets bigger, the divs try to fill the space horizontally. Since your Content3 is bigger than your others, the next row of floated divs will be placed further down to accomodate it.

One way to solve this would be to make all the divs the same height:

http://jsfiddle.net/yVwnZ/2/